# How can I decode this Json file and accessing the Country value using PHP

Tags: php, json, decode

I wanna decode a Json data using PHP, that is returned by an URL. Here is my Json data returned by an URL;

```
a:1:{s:7:"country";s:10:"United States";}
```

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks, ^_^

Comment: Welcome, Mehrab Mohul! -- The data you described in your question is not valid JSON, from what I can see. This probably explains why the answer proposed by Dashzeveg Galbadrakh uses something else, which _is_ valid.  You can validate JSON in many places, for example, on jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your data is not JSON. I wanted to clarify what this format is. This is PHP's native [serialization](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize) format.

```php
php > $array=["country"=>"United States"];
php > var_dump(serialize($array));
string(41) "a:1:{s:7:"country";s:13:"United States";}"
```

Technically, you could de-serialize it, but coming from an un-trusted source, that would be a security risk. Are your sure your data source is returning this(if so, that is highly suspect)? Is it possible something earlier in your code is serializing the value that has already been parsed?

Comment: Thank you so much akenion. Finally, I got it. Thanks a lot.
I got the JSON version of this API, and I'm not going to use this method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `json_decode()` function of PHP.

```
<?php
$jsonobj = '{"Peter":35,"Ben":37,"Joe":43}';

var_dump(json_decode($jsonobj));
?>
```

P.S: maybe the format of your json data is wrong.

Comment: Your P.S. strikes the nail on the head. That is not valid JSON data. Your JSON data is fine. The JSON data in the original question post is not valid.

Comment: Yes, I tried to decode the JSON data using an online tool, But it is saying 'Invalid JSON format'. But Exactly this JSON file is returned by the API. So then, how can I use it anyway?